# In MediaWiki, how to see a list of recent revisions if there's no edit in the last thirty days?

Tags: mediawiki

In MediaWiki, how to see a list of recent revisions if there's no edit in the last thirty days? The Special:RecentChanges page can at the most show the recent 500 changes in the last 30 days which is excluded by the premise of the question, namely there is no change in the last thirty days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Recent changes help document from MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Recent_changes) shows that you can change the time period by appending additional parameters to the URL.  Linking to the page like this should show older changes:

```
{{Special:RecentChanges/days=10000,limit=40}}
```

There are also [preferences in the Admin panel related to recent changes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Preferences#Recent_changes).   The documentation says that number of days to show is configurable:

> Days to show in recent changes: Here you can specify how far back the [recent changes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Tracking_changes) pages will go. Note that the list will stop prematurely if the number of edits is exceeded.